# Fixed point iteration in Dev C++ problems

Tags: c++, numerical-methods

Need some help with this code. I've been trying to find if the code has some error, because the approximated solution of `cos x - x` is `-1.57`, instead of `0.739`. Thanks

```
double f(double x)
{
  double y;
  y = cos(x) - x;
  return y;
}

int main()
{
  double p,p0;
  int i=1,N;
  cout<<"p0 = ";
  cin>>p0;
  cout<<"N = ";
  cin>>N;  
  while(i <= N)
  {
    p = f(p0);
    if(fabs(p-p0) < eps)
    {
      cout<<p<<endl;
      break;
    }
    cout<<"Iteration "<<i<<": p = "<<p<<endl;
    i++;
    p0 = p;
    cout<<"The solution is "<<p<<endl;
    if(i>N)
    {
      cout<<"Solution not found (method diverges)"<<endl;;
      break;
    }
  }
  cout<<"The approximated solution is x = "<<p<<" in the iteration "<<i-1<<endl;
  system("PAUSE");
  return 0;
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: which numeric method you implement and near a point of looking for the root?

Comment: Seems like I have to eliminate the if(i > N) inside the while, right?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to "solve" since `cos x - x` is not an equation. Are you looking to solve `cos x - x = 0`? (It *does* have the approximate solution 0.739.) Your code is looking for the convergence of the series `x[k+1] = cos(x[k]) - x[k]`, which is a very different thing.

Comment: why did You give subject "fixed point" ?

Comment: Because I have to create a code which finds roots of equations using the fixed point iteration. The only that has problems was this, the others code I made (bisection, Newton, etc.) were running correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method of simple iterations is the substitution x = F(x). For your equation x = cos(x).

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/YWgAH3)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

double f(double x)
{
  return cos(x);
}

int main()
{
  double p,p0=1,eps = 0.001;
  int i=1,N=1000;

  while(i <= N)
  {
    p = f(p0);
    if(fabs(p-p0) < eps)
    {
      cout<<p<<endl;
      break;
    }
    cout<<"Iteration "<<i<<": p = "<<p<<endl;
    i++;
    p0 = p;
    cout<<"The solution is "<<p<<endl;
    if(i>N)
    {
      cout<<"Solution not found (method diverges)"<<endl;;
      break;
    }
  }
  cout<<"The approximated solution is x = "<<p<<" in the iteration "<<i-1<<endl;

  return 0;
}
```